# Google App Engine: paging with IN filter

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to build a query results view with paging using `GAE` with `Java` `low level datastore API`, the problem is that one of the queries I want to use that view to display has an IN filter, but the cursor which is used to do the paging will be always `null` when executing a query with inequality filter because it will be turned into multiple queries.

Any Idea how to implement paging with queries with inequality filters?

Comment: Are you sure? Do you use ndb?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that I'm working with Java, ndb is a Paython only API I believe.

Comment: Queries with inequality filters do provide cursors. An IN query cannot provide cursors because IN is implemented using multiple queries. The best you can do to implement paging is to perform the different queries yourself, storing which query you are currently executing and the cursor for that query.